# secondary administrator for manage share point farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security

we have a SharePoint farm and i have one user account this user has full permissions to whole SharePoint farm servers and web applications.

but i want to create another user for secondary administration, this user has not like above user, but it can be mange SharePoint farm.

1. mange web applications but not any web application
2. manage service applications including search but not delete any service application
3. not change  add new  user policy and add new users in web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware about the **Delegate Administrator** group, but this is work fine for the service application but not aware if their is any for the Web Application.
[Creating a delegated administrator for a service application](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/10/creating-a-delegated-administrator-for-a-service-application/)

[Choose administrators and owners for the administration hierarchy in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263291.aspx)

But their is no OOTB way to limit this role to web application(s). I think may be try to create a custom permission level but not sure.